# Cocos2d-x: Resize window when running in win32

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have searched a lot but there are no result.

i want to check my game on screen (1080x1920) it too large for my desktop.
I set this

```
eglView->setFrameSize(1080, 1920);
```

how can i use this screen solution with smaller  size of window
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method: `eglView->setFrameZoomFactor(0.6f);`